# Keyboard shortcut to switch sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets

Is there a keyboard shortcut for switching sheets in Google Sheets? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Google's
[Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):

- Move to next sheet :
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd>
- Move to previous sheet :
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>

Comment:  And for Mac, use `option` instead of `alt`.